# CSS .class1.class2 not selecting as expected

Tags: css

I wonder why an **element has attributes of .class1 and .class2, but not .class1.class2. Please explain.** If the parent has .class1 and the element has .class2, then the element is supposed to have both classes. It has, but can't be selected using .class1.class2. In contrast, if the parent has .class1 and .class2, the child will be selected using .class1.class2, no matter what their own class attribute is.

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.class2 {
  color: green;
}

.class1.class2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class=class1>
  <p class=class2>
    HAS BOTH .class1 and .class2, but NOT .class1.class2 !?!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="class1 class2">
  <p>
    .class1.class2
  </p>
  <p class=class2>
    BUT here: .class1.class2
  </p>
  <p class=class1>
    AND HERE: .class1.class2
  </p>
  <p class=unknown>
    .class1.class2
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.class1.class2` selects all elements that explicitly have both class names in the `class` attribute. The reason the first `p` tag in your example has both the `.class1` and `.class2` styles is because the styles from the parent element 'cascade' (Cascading Style Sheets, CSS) onto the child elements. The child element isn't selected by the parent's class names, but the styles cascade onto the child unless the child overwrites them. In the second example, the parent element is selected by `.class1`, `.class2`, and `.class1.class2` since it has both classes, and those styles are passed down to the children.

Comment: Thank you @jycksyn So the emphasis is the distinction "has style" and "has style explicitly in its own class". That's why 1st p hasn't got .class1.class2. All the others produce the expected result anyway: parent has a class, so  has child.

Answer (score 1):

As the document here points out [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

> .class1.class2    -   .name1.name2    -   Selects all elements with both name1 and name2 set within its class attribute

and

> .class1 .class2   -   .name1 .name2   -   Selects all elements with name2 that is a descendant of an element with name1

The reason you get `font-weight: bold;` on the below HTML block is because the `<p>` tag [inherit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp) the style from its parent which it `.class1.class2 { font-weight: bold }`

```
<div class="class1 class2">
   <p class=class2>
      BUT here: .class1.class2
   </p>
   <p class=class1>
    AND HERE: .class1.class2
   </p>  <p class=unknown>
    .class1.class2
   </p>
</div>
```